# Lumen/Laravel - use custom router

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, lumen, lumen-5.4

Is there any out of the box solution without changing core to add custom router in to laravel or lumen. I already know that lumen is using different router from laravel, so I am wondering is there any possibility builded in core to change router?

Comment: can you ask more specific? eg. what functionality the custom router should have etc..

Comment: I doesnt matter, i just need to use different router like lumen uses different from laravel. I wonder if there is solution in framework for that or i need to mess with core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question today. After some research I found a solution which will impact the core classes minimal.

> **Note:** The following description is based on **Lumen 6.2**.
>
> Before you start; think about a proper solution, using a **middleware**.

Because of the nature of this framework, there is no way to use a custom `Router` without extending core classes and modifying the bootstrap.

Follow these steps to your custom `Router`:

## Hacky solution

### 1. Create your custom `Router`.

**Hint:** In this example `App` will be the root namespace of the Lumen project.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Routing;

class Router extends \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router
{
    public function __construct($app)
    {
        dd('This is my custom router!');
        parent::__construct($app);
    }
}
```

There is no `Interface` or similar, so you have to extend the existing `Router`. In this case, just a constructor containing a `dd()` to demonstrate, if the new `Router`ist going to be used.

### 2. Extend the `Application`

The regular `Router` will be initialized without any bindings or depentency injection in a method call inside of `Application::__construct`. Therefore you cannot overwirte the class binding for it. We have to modify this initialization proccess. Luckily Lumen is using a method just for the router initialization.

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Routing\Router;

class Application extends \Laravel\Lumen\Application
{
    public function bootstrapRouter()
    {
        $this->router = new Router($this);
    }
}
```

### 3. Tell Lumen to use our `Application`

The instance of `Application`is created relativley close at the top of our `bootstrap/app.php`.

Find the code block looking like

```php
$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    dirname(__DIR__)
);
```

and change it to

```php
$app = new App\Application(
    dirname(__DIR__)
);
```

## Proper solution

The `$router` property of `Application` is a public property. You can simply assign an instance of your custom `Router` to it.

After the instantiation of `Application` in your `bootstrap/app.php` place a

```php
$app->router = new \App\Routing\Router;
```

done.

Comment: Thanks to this I used illuminate router will a little bit of modification a lot of those features(in defining routes) are back